# Stacked LSTM with Multiple Dense Layers After

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm

[image]

Andrew Ng talks about Deep RNN architecture by stacking recurrent layers on top of each other. However, he notes that these are usually limited to 2 or 3 recurrent layers due to already complex time-dependent calculations in the structure. But he does add that people commonly add "a bunch of deep layers that are not connected horizontally" after these recurrent layers (Shown as blue boxes that extend from a[3]<1>). I am wondering if he is simply talking about stacking Dense layers on top of the recurrent layers, or is it something more complicated? Something like this in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(32, 1, input_shape), stateful=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Can I know where to find this class?

Comment: Hey Tom, you can get it on https://www.coursera.org/, I believe It is a free course there.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, **yes**, the common structure of a RNN after the hidden state includes only dense layers.

However, this can take many forms, such as a dense layer and a softmax layer when predicting the next word of a vocabulary in natural language processing (NLP) (or language modelling) applications ([examples here](https://techblog.gumgum.com/articles/deep-learning-for-natural-language-processing-part-2-rnns)).

Alternatively, for multi-objective prediction, it may the case that multiple separate dense layers are required to generate distinct outputs, such as the value and policy heads in [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).

Finally, deep LSTMs can be used as encoders which are part of a larger model that does not necessarily have to include only sequence data. For instance, diagnosing patients with a model that encodes textual notes with a LSTM and encodes images with a CNN, before passing the combined embeddings through final dense layers.